# eclipse debugging is not working as expected

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, automake

i am debugging c++ with eclipse on a linux VM.
The eclipse I am using is Kepler Service Release 1.
I compile the files using Automake.
When I try to debug in Eclipse and do stepover it sometimes jump to backward lines, sometimes it goes into the line. Also when there is a problem it just shows nothing. When I try to see variables it doesn't always succeed. It seems the Eclipse behavior is not so good.
I come from Windows programming and it looks very much like I saw when we compiled release version and tried to debug it in Visual.
Can anyone plesae assist? I can't debug like this. Is there any configuration? something I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Turn off all optimizations and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks.For future viewers I add the in our compilation we had as one of the compiling flags -O2 or -O1 to symbol optimizations. After removing them (only locally so customers still get optimized version) eclipse debugging seems much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin James stated all I needed was to turn off all optimizations.
I had -o2 flag and needed to remove it.